# How to set the route in <a> tag with user id in Laravel 6?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-6

This is My index blade where I want to click on the user name and it will redirect me on the edit user blade

```
@extends('layouts.admin')

        @section('content')
          <h1><b>Users</b></h1>
          <table class="table table-hover">
              <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th scope="col">#</th>
                  <th scope="col">Profile</th>
                  <th scope="col">Name</th>
              </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
              @if($users)
                  @foreach($users as $user)
              <tr>
                  <td>{{$user->id}}</td>
                  <td><img height="25" src="{{$user->photo ? $user->photo->file:'No photo exist'}}"></td>


                <!-- Problem is here -->
                  <td><a href="{{route('admin.users.edit', $user->id)}}" style="text-decoration: none"> 
                {{$user->name}}</a></td>


*it through an exception* 

**Route [admin.users.edit] not defined**       
              </tr>
                  @endforeach
                  @endif
              </tbody>
          </table>
        @endsection
```

If I use the `url()` method `{{url('admin/users/edit',$user->id)}}` like this it will redirect me as `admin/users/edit/1` but my route is set as `admin/users/1/edit`. How can I open this route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will not suggest to use `admin/users/1/edit` even then if you want to use this then

**Change**

```
{{url('admin/users/edit',$user->id)}}
```

**to**

```
{{url('admin/users/'.$user->id.'/edit')}}
```

Reference:

[Laravel ->URL Generation -> Generating Basic Url](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/urls#generating-basic-urls)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `route()` helper:

```
route('your.route.name1, [$user->id])
```

This way you view don't need to know how to build the url, it just need to know the route name. Any future changes in your route url will still work.

Comment: I am already using the route but it through an exception " Route [admin.users.edit] not defined"

Comment: Probably you have the wrong route name. Use `php artisan route: list` to check the name of the route.

Comment: No sir route name is correct, i double checked the route with this command "php artisan route:list"

Comment: I'm sure that the route name is wrong (actually laravel have sure). Double check it. Manually writing route urls is a bad bad practice.